# Process builder: When a Master record is updated, I want to update a field in Account which is related to a detail field related to the Master record

Tags: process-builder

MasterA --->DetailA--->Account. 
DetailA has a master detail relationship to both MasterA and Account.
Whenever fieldA is updated in MasterA, I want to update a field in Account which is related to DetailA. MasterA and Account are not directly related but only through DetailA.
Can I do this in Process builder? Can I go more than 2 levels in Process builder?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that is not possible. You can update the Account Look Up field but you cannot update any other fields on account.

Recently i created a idea regarding something similar to this but rather than updating the fields I'm looking for accessing other Master record fields in criteria.
[Process builder to be able to reference both master object through junction obj](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E95TQAS)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with process builder, but not directly in one step. What you'd have to do is on Master, set a Process Builder to update the Child records. Then, on the Child records, set a Process Builder to update the Account. Therefore, you need a total of two processes.